# Clones method is not working

Tags: java, clone

I seem to be getting an error at the catch `CloneNotSupportedException`.

```
public class Segment extends Point implements Cloneable {
    private Point p1, p2;

    public Segment() {
        this.p1 = new Point();
        this.p2 = new Point();
    }

    public Segment clone() {
        try {
            Segment cloned = (Segment) super.clone();
            cloned.p1 = (Point) p1.clone();
            cloned.p2 = (Point) p2.clone();
            return (cloned);
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException cnse) { // This is the error
            cnse.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}


package myclasses;

public class Point implements Cloneable
{
private int x, y;

public Point()
{
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
}

public Point(int X, int Y)
{
    this.x = X;
    this.y = Y;
}

public int getX()
{
    return x;
}

public int getY()
{
    return y;
}

private void setX(int x)
{
    this.x = x;
}

private void setY(int y)
{
    this.y = y;
}

public void setPoint(int newX, int newY)
{
    getX();
    getY();

    setX(x);
    setY(y);
}

public void up(int i)
{
    y = getY() + i;
}

public void down(int i)
{
    y = getY() - i;
}

public void left(int i)
{
    x = getX() - i;
}

public void right(int i)
{
    x = getX() + i;
}

public String toString()
{
    return "(" + getX() + "," + getY() + ")";
}

public boolean equals(Object obj) 
{
    if (this == obj)
        return true;

    if (obj == null)
        return false;

    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;

    Point that = (Point) obj;

    if (y != that.y)
        return false;

    if (x != that.x)
        return false;

    return true;
}

public Point clone()
{
    try
    {
        return (Point) super.clone();
    }       
    catch(CloneNotSupportedException cnse)
    {
        System.out.println(cnse);
        return null;
    }
}   
}
```

Comment: Is it `Java`?  Is your `Point` class `Cloneable`?

Comment: yes it is Java and the Point class implements Cloneable

Comment: Please put `cnse.printStackTrace();` in your `catch` and add (edit in) the result into your question.

Comment: I did that. I am still getting an error

Comment: @Avi, Add complete stacktrace of the exception that you got to your question as PM77-1, and says also include your Point class to the question.

Comment: Of course you got the error, but now you have a stack trace. Add it to your  question.

Comment: ok I added the Point class to my question

Comment: Implement `Point.clone()` - don't just call `Object.clone()`

Comment: I am sorry I am not following where I am suppose to implement Point.clone(). Please advise.  Thank you

Comment: I tested your code and I don't get the `CloneNotSupportedException`. The Segment class doesn't need to extend `Point` and you can remove the `cloned.p1 = (Point) p1.clone(); cloned.p2 = (Point) p2.clone();` lines because they're unnecessary.

Comment: I need to extend the Point class.  How else am I gonna use it in the main class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error reported by `javac` is

```
error: exception CloneNotSupportedException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException cnse) { // This is the error
```

You can declare Point.clone() like this

```
public Point clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException
```

Then `javac` won't complain. Or even simpler do not try to catch exception.